# AsyncSocket writeData Terminator

Tags: flush, asyncsocket, terminator

I am porting a Java middleware client to objC.  The java client uses the java stream.write and stream.flush at the end of the send.  For the java client to send to the Echo server I need to add the stream.writeBytes("\r\n"); followed by stream.flush for the server to bounce the message back.

I am using the asyncsocket to send messages to the middleware's server, but after successfully opening the socket, the middleware does not react to a message sent using

```
[socket writeData:sendData withTimeout:-1 tag:0];
```

Also the middleware does not react to the message in the buffer when the socket is closed.

I am currently using

```
[socket writeData:[AsyncSocket CRLFData]  withTimeout:-1 tag:0];
```

to flush the socket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this will not be the last time an assumption will come back to byte me.

I assumed that the java.io write was the same as BSD send or sendto, but from other posts, I am now assuming that the java.io.DataOutputStream is actually similar to NSMutableData and the write is appendData.  Which means that writeInt is an Endian function and flush is the actual send/sendto command.